# How to determine which port aiohttp selects when given port=0

Tags: python, aiohttp

When I use `aiohttp.web.run_app(. . ., port=0)`, I assume that it selects an arbitrary available port on which to serve. Is this correct? And if so, is there some way to figure out *what* port it's selected?

Comment: yes that assumption is correct

Comment: If it works something like `flask`, It will chose a random port.... Starting flask with port 0 will choose random high port number.

Comment: Right, but how do I know which? Is there an attribute on the app or loop?

Comment: No way. But why do you need it? Starting server on random port isn't look very useful

Comment: It's a refactoring server used by e.g. emacs. Users don't (and shouldn't normally) care which port it uses, but emacs needs to know how to talk to it after it starts. The current bottle-based version is able to print the port it chooses to stdout, and emacs parses that. I need something similar for aiohttp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `server.sockets` as in the following code:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def status(request):
    """Check that the app is properly working"""
    return web.json_response('OK')


app = web.Application()  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
app.router.add_get('/api/status', status)


def main():
    """Starts the aiohttp process to serve the REST API"""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     # continue server bootstraping
    handler = app.make_handler()
    coroutine = loop.create_server(handler, '0.0.0.0', 0)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
    print('Serving on http://%s:%s' % server.sockets[0].getsockname()) # HERE!
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
        loop.run_until_complete(handler.finish_connections(1.0))
        loop.close()
```

Comment: make_handler() is now deprecated.  Can someone suggest an alternative recipe?
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.Application.make_handler

Comment: You can use `site._server.sockets[0].getsockname()`

Answer (score 1):

When using [application runners](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#application-runners), you can pass in port 0 and access the selected port via the site object:

```py
runner = web.AppRunner(app)
await runner.setup()

site = web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', 0)
await site.start()

print('Serving on http://%s:%s' % site._server.sockets[0].getsockname())
```