# embed a aiohttp server in a PyQt application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am going to embed a aiohttp server in a PyQt application,  but when I run the code below , the Qt window couldn't show, I know it was caused by `web.run_app(app)`, I've tried to move it into a thread , but then I got `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'`, so what should I do ? I've found [asyncqt](https://github.com/gmarull/asyncqt) which might help ,but I don't know how to use it to deal with a aiohttp server.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from aiohttp import web


class ThreadGo(QThread):  # threading.Thread
    # implementing new slots in a QThread subclass is error-prone and discouraged.

    def __init__(self, parent, func, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.result = 0

        onFinished = self.kwargs.get('onFinished')
        self.finished.connect(onFinished) if onFinished else None  # 用lambda还不行呢

        self.finished.connect(self.deleteLater)
        self.start()

    def run(self):

        self.result = self.func(*self.args)  # deleteLater


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.setUpHTTPServer()

    def setUpHTTPServer(self):
        async def hello(request):
            return web.Response(text="Hello, world")
        app = web.Application()
        app.add_routes([web.get('/', hello)])
        web.run_app(app)
        # ThreadGo(self, lambda:web.run_app(app))#get RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv, exit

    a = QApplication(argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    exit(a.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following example I show how to use Qt with the aiohttp server:

```
import asyncio
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from asyncqt import QEventLoop

from aiohttp import web


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.setup_server()

    def setup_server(self):
        self.app.add_routes([web.get("/", self.hello)])

    @cached_property
    def app(self):
        return web.Application()

    async def hello(self, request):
        return web.Response(text="Hello, world")

    def run(self):
        web.run_app(self.app)


def main():
    import sys

    a = QApplication(sys.argv)

    loop = QEventLoop(a)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    w = Window()
    w.show()

    w.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Which port does this server listen?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610441/how-to-determine-which-port-aiohttp-selects-when-given-port-0, by default 8000